# Search for string from each line of cell in another column and if match is found, insert row below the found match in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, insert, contains

How can I check for value from a column "B" cell (it could contain multiple lines) is it in column "A" and if it is - inserts hole row (e.g. in which I have values m32\nm83\nm18) below the row in which match is found in column "A" (e.g. m32)?

This is data frame:

df

```
  A      B                  C
  m55    m32\nm83\nm18      123
  m56    m12                546
  m68
  m32
  m83
  m65
  m73    m77\nm78           558
  m23
  m98
  m77
  m18
  m4
  m12
  m78
```

And this is what I want to get:

df

```
   A      B                  C
  m55    m32\nm83\nm18      123
  m56    m12                546
  m68
  m32
  m55    m32\nm83\nm18      123
  m83
  m55    m32\nm83\nm18      123
  m65
  m73    m77\nm78           558
  m23
  m98
  m77
  m73    m77\nm78           558
  m18
  m55    m32\nm83\nm18      123
  m4
  m12
  m56    m12                546
  m78
  m73    m77\nm78           558
```

I tried whit this:

```
def insert_row(idx, df, df_insert):
    return df.iloc[:idx, ].append(df_insert).append(df.iloc[idx:, ]).reset_index(drop = True)

dfB = dfB[dfB.apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, str))]
dfBidx = dfB.index

j=0
for b in dfBidx:
    try:
        idx = df.index[df["A"].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, str)).str.contains("|".join(dfB[b].split("\n")))]
        for i in idx:
            i+=j
            df_new = df.loc[i]
            df = insert_row(i+j+1, df, df_new)
            j+= int(df_new.size/len(df_new.columns.values))
    except:
        pass
```

Is it some other way to do this? I have a problem with NaN values in column "A", and generally, have some mismatching in using of functions:

> str(), 
>   contains(),
>   apply()

EDIT:

I have the second data frame (df2) from which I am extracting rows and inserting in the df. I am extracting rows from the "test" to "test" in column "Keyword".

df2

```
  Keyword      B                  C
  test         m32\nm83\nm18      123
  something
  something
  something
  test
  something
  something
  test         m12                546
  something
  test         m77\nm78           558
  test
  something
```

So, at the end I need this:

df

```
  A         Keyword      B                  C
  m55                    m32\nm83\nm18      123
  m56                    m12                546
  m68
  m32
            test         m32\nm83\nm18      123
            something
            something
            something
  m83
            test         m32\nm83\nm18      123
            something
            something
            something
  m65
  m73                    m77\nm78           558
  m23
  m98
  m77
            test         m77\nm78           558
  m18
            test         m32\nm83\nm18      123
            something
            something
            something
  m4
  m12
            test         m12                546
            something
  m78
            test         m77\nm78           558
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution working with default `RangeIndex`.

Crate dictionary of index of inserted rows with index of source row (`d1`) and in list comprehension repeat rows, also add `0.5` for correct ordering. Last [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) all together, [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) and create default index by `reset_index`:

```
d = df['B'].dropna().to_dict()
print (d)
{0: 'm32\\nm83\\nm18', 1: 'm12', 6: 'm77\\nm78'}

d1 = {k: df.index[df['A'].str.contains("|".join(v.split("\\n")))] for k, v in d.items()}
print (d1)
{0: Int64Index([3, 4, 10], dtype='int64'), 
 1: Int64Index([12], dtype='int64'), 
 6: Int64Index([9, 13], dtype='int64')}

L = [pd.concat([df.loc[[k]]] * len(v)).set_index([v + .5]) for k, v in d1.items()]

df = pd.concat([df] + L).sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
      A              B      C
0   m55  m32\nm83\nm18  123.0
1   m56            m12  546.0
2   m68            NaN    NaN
3   m32            NaN    NaN
4   m55  m32\nm83\nm18  123.0
5   m83            NaN    NaN
6   m55  m32\nm83\nm18  123.0
7   m65            NaN    NaN
8   m73       m77\nm78  558.0
9   m23            NaN    NaN
10  m98            NaN    NaN
11  m77            NaN    NaN
12  m73       m77\nm78  558.0
13  m18            NaN    NaN
14  m55  m32\nm83\nm18  123.0
15   m4            NaN    NaN
16  m12            NaN    NaN
17  m56            m12  546.0
18  m78            NaN    NaN
19  m73       m77\nm78  558.0
```

Comment: @jezrael-thank you. I will check again because some things I do not understand. Why do we need 0.5?

Comment: @slobokv83 - it is nice trick for correct ordering. If need add row after `[3, 4, 10],` create DataFrame with `[3.5, 4.5, 10.5],` , so after join togehter and sorting get correct positions.

Comment: @jezrael-aha...thank you. It could be any value below 1.0, but not smaller than 0.5, right?

Comment: @slobokv83 - exactly, need number bellow 1

Comment: @jezrael-and when I want to insert a variable number of rows (from the position which is in this example to the position when some keyword appears in the particular column)?...because of that I used in my example `j+= int(df_new.size/len(df_new.columns.values))`

Comment: @slobokv83 - hmmm, then solution should be add new dataframe with index `3.3, 3.6, 3.9` for add 3 rows between 3 and 4 index. But not sure what rows should be added. Can you expalin more?

Comment: @jezrael-I edit the post. I have the second data frame from which I am extracting based on the same principle if the match is found.

Comment: @slobokv83 - Can you create new question?